# Arrange the array in table format

Tags: php, arrays, magento

This is my array and I want to set this array in table format and I want to set first row as show below:

```
    $_tierPrices = Array
(
    Array
        (   
            "price_qty" => "4",
            "price" => "143.00",
            "savePercent" => "8"      
        ),

    Array
        (   
            "price_qty" => "12",
            "price" => "133.0000",
            "savePercent" => "15"
        ),

    Array
        (   
            "price_qty" => "20",
            "savePercent" => "18",
            "price" => "128.0000"
        ),

    Array
        (
            "price_qty" => "40",
            "savePercent" => "21",
            "price" => "123.0000"
        )
);
```

I want to set this array value in table format as shown below

This is my table row:

```
4   | 12 |  20 | 40 |
```

I need this:

```
4 - 11 | 12 - 19 | 20 - 39 | 40+ |
```

Please advise.

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: what is `var_dump($_tierPrices);` ?

Comment: @Dray - Please find the array result in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

> Tier Price Array

```
<?php
    $_tierPrices = array (
        array
        (
            "price_qty" => "4",
            "price" => "143.00",
            "savePercent" => "8"      
        ),

        array
        (   
            "price_qty" => "12",
            "price" => "133.0000",
            "savePercent" => "15"
        ),

        array
        (   
            "price_qty" => "20",
            "savePercent" => "18",
            "price" => "128.0000"
        ),

        array
        (
            "price_qty" => "40",
            "savePercent" => "21",
            "price" => "123.0000"
        )
    );
?>
```

> Tier Price Table

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Header</td></tr>
    <?php $_qtyRow = '<tr>'; ?>
    <?php $_priceRow = '<tr>'; ?>
    <?php $_saveRow = '<tr>'; ?>
    <?php
        $size = count($_tierPrices);
        foreach($_tierPrices as $index => $_tierPrice) {
            if($index < $size-1) {
                $_qty = $_tierPrice['price_qty'] . ' - ' . ($_tierPrices[$index+1]['price_qty'] - 1);
            } else {
                $_qty = $_tierPrice['price_qty'] . '+';             
            }
            $_qtyRow .= '<td>'.$_qty.'</td>';
            $_priceRow .= '<td>'.$_tierPrice['price'].'</td>';
            $_saveRow .= '<td>'.$_tierPrice['savePercent'].'</td>';
        }

        $_qtyRow .= '</tr>';
        $_priceRow .= '</tr>';
        $_saveRow .= '</tr>';

        echo $_qtyRow;
        echo $_priceRow;
        echo $_saveRow;
    ?>
    <tr><td>Footer</td></tr>
</table>
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you have in `$_tierPrices` so i am giving you an example by for some other data.

```
$arr = array('4','12','20','40');  //suppose you have array like this
$end = end($arr);  //We need to find last element of the array to show like 40+

for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++){
  if($arr[$i] != $end){
    echo $arr[$i]."-".($arr[$i+1]-1)." | ";    
  } else{
    echo $arr[$i]."+";    
  }
}
```

Output will be like

```
4-11 | 12-19 | 20-39 | 40+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo "<table><tr>";//opening the table
$first_iteration = FALSE;

foreach ($_tierPrices as $value)
{
  if (!$first_iteration)//code that only runs on the first iteration
  {
    $first_iteration = TRUE;
    $buffer_value = $value;
  }
  else {//code that runs after the first iteration
    $buff = ((integer)$value)-1;//calculation1 value previous
    $output = $buffer_value."-".$buff;
    echo "<td>".$output."</td>";
    $buffer_value = $value;
  }
}
echo "<td>".$buffer_value."+</td>";
echo "</tr></table>";//closing the table
?>
```

let me know if that worked for you :)